Das Auto, von dem /davon
Welche Variante von den Sätzen ist korrekt?
1.1. Das Auto, von dem ich geträumt habe, kann nicht mehr in meinem Land gekauft werden.
1.2. Das Auto, davon ich geträumt habe, kann nicht mehr in meinem Land gekauft werden.
2.1. Das Schönste, an das ich mich erinnern kann, ist Arina.
2.2. Das Schönste, woran ich mich erinnern kann, ist Arina.

Welche Sätze hältst du für richtig und welche nicht und warum?

Sollte Arina eine Person sein, könnte sie sich vom neutralen das herabgesetzt fühlen.

@guidot: Unfug.

1.2 ist im Hochdeutsch nicht korrekt - vielleicht gibt es aber einen Dialekt, in dem das geht.
Die anderen Formulierungen sind alle korrekt.

1.2. war mal korrekt. Ein Beispiel ist der Text von Vom Himmel hoch, da komm ich her von M. Luther: Der guten Mär bring ich so viel, davon ich singn und sagen will, oder auch Der schönste Ort davon ich weiß, das ist ein kühler Keller von W. Wackernagel. 2.1. ist mittlerweile üblich, gilt aber als weniger gehoben als 2.2
